# Shell Command with SoapUI groovy

Tags: groovy, continuous-integration, sh, soapui

So I'm trying to run a shell script on an automated SoapUI project which is execute in continuous integration. I need to send a few parameters and an SQL query to the script so I'm trying to execute a command similar to this:

```
/path/to/file.sh param1 param2 "sql query"
```

If I log the command and execute it manually it works perfectly but when groovy runs it the "sql query" argument is split into multiple arguments for every space.

I've tried running the command with

```
String command = "/path/to/file.sh param1 param2 \"sql query\""
def proc = command.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(5000)
```

I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong.
Best regards

Comment: Can you try: `["/path/to/file.sh", "param1", "param2", "sql query"].execute()`?  What's the response you're getting?

Comment: It worked great @tim_yates Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Grooy also arrays (arrays are internal lists) have a execute method. It's usually much safer to execute commands over arrays.

```
def command = ['/path/to/file.sh', 'param1', 'param2', 'sql query']
def proc = command.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(5000)
```

Comment: Is it safe to use 'sql query' since an sql query itself uses ' for string values?

Comment: @JSantos you can wrap your sql statement with " - even it's in Groovy a special dynamic string type it will work also without the dynamic replacements